# How can I Import A Namespace from A File in A Seperate Folder in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

How do I bring into the current namespace an extension method (see below) into scope, when the file this class is defined in is in another folder?

When `StringHandler.cs` is in the `Product` folder, I can include `using Utilities;` in `Product.cs`, but when it is in a separate folder, alongside the `Project` folder (in the `Utilities` folder), I can't figure out how to include it. Can someone please explain how I can use the using keyword in this case? For instance, where is `using` really pointing to on my file system (do I need to specify the using directory relative to my `csproj` file or to my `CallCenter.sln` file?)?

```
│   CallCenter.sln
│
├───src
│   ├───Project
│   │   │   Product.cs
|   |   |   Project.csproj
│   │   ├───bin
│   │   │   └───...
│   │   │
│   │   └───obj
│   │       └───...         
│   │
│   └───Utilities
│           StringHandler.cs
```

**StringHandler.cs**

```
namespace Utilities
{
    public static class StringHandler
    {
        public static string InsertSpaces(this string source)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
            {
                foreach (char letter in source)
                {
                    if (char.IsUpper(letter))
                    {
                        result = result.Trim();
                        result += " ";
                    }
                    result += letter;
                }
            }
            return result.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add the cs to the project.  The using statement is the library name and has nothing to do with the path where the file is located.  To add the cs file to project using VS menu : Project : Add Existing Item : Browse towards the cs file.  Once the file is added you can then add the namespace to other modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder in which a `.cs` file is located has no meaning during compilation. The `using` statement just allows types from a certain namespace to be found. To be able to use the extension method, make sure that:

- The namespace is included (`using Utilities;`)
- The file (`StringHandler.cs`) is included in your project *or* in another project that your current project has a reference to

Comment: `or in another project that your current project has a reference to`. Does this mean I need to `dotnet new console` in the `Utilities` folder, and include a `<PackageRefernce>` and `Include` directive in the `Project` folder's `Project.csproj` file?

Comment: I _think_ you just want to add `StringHandler.cs` to the `Project.csproj` project, unless you want to put these utilities in a separate dll.

Comment: I want them in a separate dll. But does it make sense to keep them in a separate dll? I want to store utility methods and extension methods separately from my business logic and I find that keeping them separate helps to add a mental barrier.

I did exactly what I mentioned above and it worked without issue. Looks like the csproj files are key. As long as their location is specified there, everything else should be fine (with the namespace included). I did the following in Project.csproj:

  `<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Utilities\Utilities.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: for such purposes you need to create a separate library project and reference this project everywhere you need, adding project reference, this will allow to use include project namespace with `using`

Comment: If you have a bunch of related functionality, it would definitely make sense to put them in a separate dll for reuse (for instance, take a look at https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-string (not my project), a dll  that contains all kinds of features similar to your extension method).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I bring into the current namespace an extension method (see below) into scope, when the file this class is defined in is in another folder?

Where the file is defined, folder-wise, is irrelevant. By convention, the folder structure on disk mimics the namespace, but it does not have to. A `using` "brings" a type into the namespace. (Not really "brings" -- more like "makes available to").

As far as the source type being available to the namespace in the target project, it has to be available physically to your project via a

- direct reference to the source project from the target project
- direct reference to a source NuGet package from the target project
- indirect reference to the source project via a transitive dependency of another project from the target project
- indirect reference to the source NuGet package via a transitive dependency of another project or NuGet package from the target project

and logically by

- a `using` statement to the source type

> When StringHandler.cs is in the Product folder, I can include using Utilities; in Product.cs, but when it is in a separate folder, alongside the Project folder (in the Utilities folder), I can't figure out how to include it. Can someone please explain how I can use the using keyword in this case?

You can't use a `using` to get to `StringHandler` as you've currently defined your structure. The reason is that `StringHandler` is *not* a part of any project. Because it's not a part of any project, it violates the rules I listed above.

To use the `using` as you expect, you have two simple choices in your case:

- add `StringHandler` directly to the project that needs it, or if you want `StringHandler` to be separate, add it to another project and reference that project from the target project.
- with a little more Kung Fu, leave `StringHandler` where it is (project-less) and include a *link* to that file in the target project. This is cheating a little bit: it makes it look like `StringHandler` was in `Project` all along. This case is rare; I personally only do this when I want to include, for example, common assembly attributes, not common *code*.

> For instance, where is using really pointing to on my file system (do I need to specify the using directory relative to my csproj file or to my CallCenter.sln file?)?

Again, forget about the directory/folder/disk structure. Only think about the in-solution physical references (project/NuGet based) and logical references (namespace-based). They usually match the directory/folder/disk, but they don't have to.